# Checking if a listview item contains a string, and get the position

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-adapter

I have an app that would check if a listview item contains a specific string, and then retrieve the item position with it's details, but all I have seen in tutorials and in stack are getting them on button click.

But I am trying to get the position when the data retrieved from the server and check if any item retrieved from the server contains the specific string. How would I be able to retrieve the data from the item that contains the specific string?

This is my MainActivity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_orders_page);

orderID = new ArrayList<>();
orderStatus = new ArrayList<>();

 adapter = new viewOrderAdapter(viewOrdersPage.this, orderID, orderUserNumber, orderDateTime, orderNameJSON, orderLatLong, orderStatus);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    getData();

}

  public void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Fetching data...", false, false);
    String url = DATA_URL + textUsername.getText().toString().trim();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    showLIST(response);
                    loading.dismiss();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        loading.dismiss();

                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Please connect to the Internet", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                getData();
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Check if you have Internet Access", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                getData();
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "Check if you have Internet Access", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        snackbar.setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                getData();
                            }
                        });
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
private void showLIST(JSONArray jsonArray) {
    JSONObject obj = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        try {
            obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            orderID.add(obj.getString(ORDERID));
            orderUserNumber.add(obj.getString(ORDERUSERNUMBER));
            orderDateTime.add(obj.getString(ORDERDATETIME));
            orderNameJSON.add(obj.getString(ORDERNAME));
            orderLatLong.add(obj.getString(ORDERLATLONG));
            orderStatus.add(obj.getString(ORDERSTATUS));


//THIS IS WHERE I INITIALLY THOUGHT THE CHECKING WITH OCCUR, THOUGH IT CHECKS IF A ITEM CONTAINS A SPECIFIC STRING.
//BUT IT RETRIEVES ONLY THE FIRST ORDERID EVEN IF IT DOES NOT CONTAIN THE STRING, AND YES IT IS WRONG BECAUSE IT DOES NOT SPECIFY THE SPECIFIC POSITION OF THE ITEM HAHA! SO THIS IS MY PROBLEM.

            if(orderStatus.contains("DECLINED"))
            {

                 }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    viewOrderAdapter listOrderAdapter = new viewOrderAdapter(this,orderID, orderUserNumber, orderDateTime, orderNameJSON, orderLatLong, orderStatus);
    listView.setAdapter(listOrderAdapter);
}
```

This is my Adapter View:

```
public class viewOrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;

private ArrayList<String> orderID;
private ArrayList<String> orderStatus;


public viewOrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderID, ArrayList<String> orderStatus){
    this.context = context;
    this.orderID = orderID;
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderID.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return orderID.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View listView;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_orders_item, parent, false);

    TextView id = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderID);
    TextView status = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.orderStatus);


    id.setText(orderID.get(position));
    status.setText(orderStatus.get(position));

    return listView;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: Not sure would this work : `if(obj.getString(ORDERSTATUS).equals("DECLINED"));`

Comment: @JohnJoe Hey sir, yes it works. It tells me if a item contains a DELCINED string, but then how would I retrieved the specfic ORDERID of the item that contains the string sir? :D

Comment: In the `if` blocks, you can add a function `getOrderId(i)`, then retrieve the **ORDERID** based on the `i` from database.

Comment: Are you saying you want to retrieve item position before setting the adapter or after setting the adapter?

Comment: @SidharthAnil before sir. So when the data is retrieved from the server, I will now which orderid contains a string with DECLINED